# Использование C# библиотеки Атол в приложении UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Привет! Столкнулся с проблемкой. У Атол есть драйвера версии 8_10_03_00 для ККМ. Стоит задача, интегрировать взаимодействие с кассой в приложении под UWP. У Атол эта либа идёт как COM, в итоге reference на нее можно указать только в приложении на .net framework. В UWP приложении нету возможности добавить такой объект. 
Можно отдельно взять файл библиотеки драйверов FprnM1C.dll и добавить его в проект. Но тогда студия ругается таким сообщением "interop type cannot be embedded use the application interface instead". В wpf проблема решалась выставлением свойства "Embeded interop types" в значение "false" в Properties. К сожалению в UWP в Properties нету такого свойства O_o. Может кто-нибудь подскажет, как быть в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Я работал с драйвером для ТСД (PDX1C.dll) в WPF, там я библиотеку встраивал, потому что ругался компилятор. Сейчас, ради интереса, создал проект UWP, добавил на эту либу ссылку - сборка прошла без проблем, ни ошибок, ни предупреждений. VS Community 2015 с последними обновлениями.